# Excel VBA - How To Insert Value without Formula?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

The formula shows on each cell after execution,  is it possible not to show the formula ?

VBA code:

```
Set rngCell = wbk.Worksheets("TEST1").Range("C1")

  For i = 1 To 81
    rngCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = "=round((COUNTIF('T2'!C[7],RC[-2])/60),2)"
    rngCell.Offset(i, 1).Value = "=round((COUNTIF('T3'!C[6],RC[-3])/60),2)"
    rngCell.Offset(i, 2).Value = "=round((COUNTIF('T4'!C[5],RC[-4])/60),2)"
    rngCell.Offset(i, 3).Value = "=round((COUNTIF('T5'!C[4],RC[-5])/60),2)"
  Next
```

Answer (score 2):

There are LOTS of ways to do this, Probably the simplest it to add this in after the loop:

```
wbk.Worksheets("TEST1").Range("C2:F82").Value =  wbk.Worksheets("TEST1").Range("C2:F82").Value
```

### OR

```
wbk.Worksheets("TEST1").Range("C2:F" & i).Value =  wbk.Worksheets("TEST1").Range("C2:F" i).Value
```

... I hope I got the cell references right...

Comment: +1 though... It should be `C2:F82`, because i starts at 1. And your second one shouldn't have the `-1`, because that'll point at row 81 instead of 82.

Comment: ... I'll trust you, thanks :) - I just focused on the actual problem at hand more so than trying to calculate the ranges. I updated the solution accordingly.